# Getting UL border to wrap only around text

Tags: html, css, html-lists, block

I have a `UL` that I'm using for a menue of styled. Unfortunately, when I try to add a boarder it goes across the whole screen because they are `li` elements (and are `display: block`). I also don't want to define a fixed width for the elements, and instead want the width to be the width necessary for the text.

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5xu6t/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would require adding extra tag into your html but it seems to do what you want.

```
<li><span>Test</span></li>
```

And bodge the css a bit too.

http://jsfiddle.net/BVYM7/

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
<li><span>Test</span></li>

span{
    border: solid 1px red;
}
```